# Install PDFlib on XAMPP OS X 10.13.5

Tags: pdf, xampp, php

I need to install PDFlib required for one module build for a magento website.
What I did so far is:

1. go to https://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-product-family/ and download the latest version for OS X.
2. print out a phpinfo to find out my extension_dir path /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226
3. copy the the php_pdflib.so in the extension_dir folder
4. open /Applications/XAMPP/xampfiles/etc/php.ini and put the following extension=php_pdflib.so
5. restart apache
6. check in the phpinfo - nothing there
7. run php -m and php -i from terminal and PDFlib is listed

I even try installing with the brew command

What I've done wrong?

Comment: What gives `php --info |grep extension`?

Comment: php -i |grep PDF

`PDFlib
PDFlib Support => enabled
PDFlib GmbH Binary-Version => 9.1.2p1 `

Comment: So ... what is your problem?

Comment: it's not showing up on phpinfo(); and I still get the undefined Class error

Comment: Did you check you don't have a 32/64bits issue?

Comment: @Bsquare, how do I check that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have either an issue with 32/64bits mixing, or TS/NTS (TS stands for Thread Safe). You can check with `php -i |grep -i Thread`; for 32/64 bits, if you are on a *nix OS, you can use file on the php executable.

Comment: `php -i |grep -i Thread` gives me `Thread Safety => disabled`. 
I had to copy the DSO from php 560 nts as I had the following message when I run php -v 
`Warning: PHP Startup: PDFlib: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20131226,TS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20131226,NTS
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Ha! You see the issue, the module is the TS version, but the PHP version is the NTS one (again: TS=Thread Safe).

Comment: yes, but after that I have copied the file from NTS version and the error was gone.
now, I don't have errors, but it's still not working

Comment: Ok, so at least we are sure you need (and have) the NTS version. I'll check what you miss.

Comment: What gives `php -version`, and what is the exact relative path of the `php_pdflib.so` you copy?

Comment: `php - version` gives me this:
`PHP 5.6.32 (cli) (built: Nov  8 2017 18:18:29) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies`
the path where I copied the `php_pdflib.so` is the the following:
`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226`